# Ccache hits only once during kernel build

Tags: kernel, cache

I installed and set up ccache and built the kernel with it. Here are the stats:

```
cache directory                     /home/marcin/.ccache
cache hit (direct)                     1
cache hit (preprocessed)               0
cache miss                         15878
called for link                       31
called for preprocessing            2655
unsupported source language          102
no input file                       4733
files in cache                     35882
cache size                           2.7 Gbytes
max cache size                       3.0 Gbytes
```

Why is ccache so inefficient for me? Why do I get so many misses?

Comment: Did you build the kernel twice?

Comment: No (15 characters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ccache` will only reduce compilation time if you compile the same code several times; it's perfectly normal to see (nearly) only cache misses when compiling a project once, because the code being compiled hasn't been cached.

Comment: Additionally, some software uses explicit absolute paths to the compilers, which, if `ccache` has not been properly set up using "the symlink method" (see the `ccache` manual), won't invoke `ccache` at all.